# C# SDL.NET, when trying to SetVideoMode using OpenGL nothing happens. What can I be doing wrong?

Tags: c#, opengl, sdl

I am trying to create an application that will need to use double buffering (for purpose of Vsync). I am using SDL.NET. From what I understood, in order to have double buffering, I have to SetVideoMode with OpenGl = true.

Here's the code:

```
        Video.Initialize();

        Video.GLSetAttribute(OpenGLAttr.DoubleBuffer, 1);
        Video.GLSetAttribute(OpenGLAttr.SwapControl, 1);
        Video.GLSetAttribute(OpenGLAttr.RedSize, 8);
        Video.GLSetAttribute(OpenGLAttr.GreenSize, 8);
        Video.GLSetAttribute(OpenGLAttr.BlueSize, 8);
        Video.GLSetAttribute(OpenGLAttr.DepthSize, 16);

        Video.SetVideoMode(VideoInfo.ScreenWidth, VideoInfo.ScreenHeight, false, true, true, true);
```

If 4th parameter (bool opengl) is false, it works - a new fullscreen window is created and displayed (but I assume, the OpenGLAttr's set above are meaningless in this case).

If 4th parameter is true, nothing happens - a new window gets created (at least, it appears in the list of open windows) but I cannot alt+tab into it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I see that the problem was, I didn't output anything on the screen - doing Video.GLSwapBuffers() made the black screen appear.